# equi-join with mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to join a couple of tables where table videos has:

```
video_id
user_id
camera_id
video_size
video_datetime
video_length
video_url
```

and table cameras has:

```
camera_id
user_id
camera_hash
camera_type
camera_status
camera_name
camera_quality
camera_user
camera_pass
camera_ip
camera_port
camera_url
```

So user_id and camera_id are common.  I'm trying to get data showing me the video size, date/time, length and camera name.  I can do this query:

```
SELECT videos.video_size, videos.video_datetime, videos.video_length,
cameras.camera_name 
FROM videos, cameras 
WHERE videos.user_id = cameras.user_id 
and videos.user_id=69 and cameras.camera_id=73
```

This is fine and gets me what I want but I need to calculate the number 73 (getting the user_id of 69 is not a problem).  So I can do this with:

```
SELECT camera_id from videos where user_id=69
```

This can return multiple values...so more processing.  I'm wondering if there is a better or more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT videos.video_size, videos.video_datetime, videos.video_length, 
       cameras.camera_name
  FROM videos inner join cameras using (user_id, camera_id)
 WHERE videos.user_id=69
```